# Application with Spring Cloud Sleuth reporting to Jaeger with OpenTracing is not using the BraveTracer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin, jaeger

Following Spring Cloud Sleuth's documentation I've set up a Spring Boot application with a Zipkin client:

Gradle config:

```
"org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth",
"org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin"
```

With this I start a Zipkin Server instance:

```
docker run -d -p 9411:9411 openzipkin/zipkin
```

And I get traces in Zipkin. So far so good.

Then I switch to a Jaeger server:

```
docker run -d -e COLLECTOR_ZIPKIN_HTTP_PORT=9411 --name jaeger -p 5775:5775/udp -p 6831:6831/udp -p 6832:6832/udp -p 5778:5778 -p 16686:16686 -p 14268:14268 -p 9411:9411 jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
```

And without any change to my application I can see those traces in Jaeger. Great.

Sleuth docs states:

15.1. OpenTracing

> Spring Cloud Sleuth is compatible with OpenTracing. If you have
>   OpenTracing on the classpath, we automatically register the
>   OpenTracing Tracer bean. If you wish to disable this, set
>   spring.sleuth.opentracing.enabled to false

Following this I added the Open Tracing dependency:

```
"io.opentracing.brave:brave-opentracing",
```

During startup the `OpentracingAutoConfiguration` creates a `BraveTracer`.

The point is I've placed a breakpoint in methods such as `scopeManager()`, `activeSpan()`, `activateSpan()`, `buildSpan()` from that `BraveTracer` and none of them is invoked during the execution of the application; the traces keep showing up in Jaeger though.

What am I missing here?